# git submodule foreach - check if submodule path start with

Tags: bash, git

I'm trying to run some actions on a subset of the submodules in my repository. I found that the way to do that should be to use git submodule foreach and then add a custom bash command. This is the code that I'm trying to run:

```
git submodule foreach \
'
   echo $sm_path
   if [[ $sm_path = my_submodule_name* ]] ; then 
      echo found submodule starting with my_submodule_name
   fi
'
```

The problem is that it is giving me a syntax error, even though the  bash syntax should be the correct. I tried to add `bash -c` after `git submodule foreach`. This seems to solve the syntax error but then I do not get anymore the variable that should contain the submodule path ($sm_path).

It looks like the chicken and egg problem. Any suggestion to make it running?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `/bin/sh` is not Bash do not use bashisms. Compare using `[ x = y ]` instead of `[[ x = y ]]`. To test for a substring at the start use `grep`:

```
git submodule foreach \
'
   echo $sm_path
   if echo $sm_path | grep -q ^my_submodule_name || :; then 
      echo found submodule starting with my_submodule_name
   fi
'
```

To use Bash use the following syntax:

```
git submodule foreach \
'bash -c "
   echo $sm_path
   if [[ $sm_path = my_submodule_name* ]] ; then 
      echo found submodule starting with my_submodule_name
   fi
"'
```

Answer (score 2):

There are distros whose default scripting shells take old-school to a fault. Debian switched from bash to dash a while back for instance, so all its kids probably have too. A works-even-on-shells-from-the-1970's syntax is

```
case $sm_path in my_submodule_name*) doit ;;  esac
```